# Referring subquery variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Query like this

```
(select max(mon_sal.(salary)) from 
(select salary from employee group by employee_id) as mon_sal)
```

whereas in above query,I am using **mon_sal.salary** to refer the **subquery variable.**

**Problem starts here :**

But Now similarly i needed to refer the following variable

```
(select max(mon_sal.(month*salary)) from 
(select month*salary from employee group by employee_id) as mon_sal) as max_mon_sal
```

where i wanted to refer the subquery with two variables with multiplication operator ,i am not able to refer the subquery variable.

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mon_sal.() function. Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result

Comment: Hold on a sec... are you sure your original query worked as intended? `select salary from employee group by employee_id`... What `salary` value would you expect here, since you're grouping by `employee_id` and are not using an aggregate function on `salary`.  Perhaps you should clarify your requirements, along with sample data + expected results.

Comment: And the table structure is suspect.  I would expect `employee_id` to be the primary key of an `employee` table. But then, why would you ever do a `group by employee_id` if you only have one row per `employee_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias

```
(select max(mon_sal.(my_alias)) from  (
       select distinct  month*salary as my_alias 
       from employee  )   mon_sal)    max_mon_sal
```

Comment: Who is `select month*salary ... group by employee_id`. this query return random month and random salary for any employee. What is meaningless

Comment: @Mike  . correct  ..  group by is unuseful  could use distinct